# How to create an object with 2 keys and 1 value?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to create an object with 2 keys for 1 value.

For example, for only 1 key I would be doing this:

```
d['a1'] = 1
```

I was wondering how to achieve something similar to:

```
d['a1']['b1'] = 1
```

But when I try this format I get

```
Cannot set property 'b1' of undefined
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this?

**EDIT**

After reading answers and comments, now I know what I want is an object and will give more detail on what I'm trying to achieve.

```
keyOne ["Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Kiwi", "Mango", "Prune", "Peach", "apple"]
keyTwo["Bob", "Toto", "Tata", "Tutu"]
for(let i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < arrayTwo.length; j++){
      //add value to object { keyOne[i]: { keyTwo[j]: "${i} + ${j}"} }
    }
}
console.log(object[Banana][Bob])
console.log(object[Banana][Toto])
console.log(object[Orange][Bob])
```

output :

```
0 + 0
0 + 1
1 + 1
```

Comment: You seem to be describing an object of objects: `{ a1: { b1: 1 } }`.

Comment: What you describe is not possible. `d['a1'] = 1` is a simple object = `d = { a1: 1 }` while `d['a1']['b1'] = 1` is an object there the values are other objects: `d = { a1: { b1: 1 } }`. You cannot both set the `a1` property to a number *and* still use it as an object - it's one or the other. Well, barring some trickery with proxies, but it just suggests [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What do you really want? What I understand is that you want to have `d["a1"]` have the exact same value as `d["b1"]`, where the value is 1.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create this structure

```js
var d = {
    a1:{
      b1:1
    }
 }
console.log(d['a1']['b1'])
```

EDIT:
If you want to create this dynamically:

```js
var key1 = ["a1"], Key2 = ["b1"];
var d = {};
for(let i =0; i< key1.length; i++){
  d[key1[i]] = {[Key2[i]] : 1}
}

console.log(d);
console.log(d['a1']['b1'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there a way to do that but dynamically? In my case, what I actually have is 2 array of string KeyOne[] and KeyTwo[] and for each pair I have a value. So I wanted to do 2 for loop and add a new pair of {key1: { key2 : value} }

Comment: Yes you can do so dynamically. Can you provide the exact input of arrays and the output?

Comment: @dbJoker See the Edit

Comment: This works but only if there is only 1 key2 for the key1, I edited my question to add more context

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn’t natively include a type called “Dictionary” but contains a type called "Object" where we can achieve `d['a1']` but not an assignment in a value that not already exist.

So you need to create the object structure before the assignment.

**Edit:**

Here, if i understood the problem, the code that you want to achieve:

```js
arr1 = ["Banana", "Orange", "Pear", "Kiwi", "Mango", "Prune", "Peach", "apple"]
arr2 = ["Bob", "Toto", "Tata", "Tutu"]

result = {}
for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    let parent = result[arr1[i]] = {}

    for(let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
        parent[arr2[j]] =  `${i} + ${j}`;
    }
}
console.log(result.Banana.Bob)
console.log(result.Banana.Toto)
console.log(result.Orange.Bob)
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is an object with two properties 'a1' and 'b1'. Each property equals 1

```js
var d = {
  'a1': 1,
  'b1': 1
}

console.log(d);
console.log(d['a1']);
console.log(d['b1']);
```

Answer (score -3):

As far as i understand "two keys for one value", you almost got it right. Try:

```
d['a1'] = d['b1'] = 1
```

Comment: downvoters, why are you so sure OP meant nested dictionaries?